# Issuing http get request and accessing the data I'm getting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my app, I'm issuing get request to retrieve JSON from my server.

```
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/documents/2.json')
            .success(
                    function(success){
                        console.log("Success");
                    })
            .error(
                    function(error){
                            console.log("error has occurred")
        });
```

Right now, I do successfully get 200 response, but I'm not sure how to access the json file I'm getting from the URL in my web app. I assume there's gotta be something like `function(JSONData)`  but not sure how to implement it in my function above.

I'm issuing this in client side(Written in Angular) and getting the data from the server(written in Rails). My front end (in Angular) is part of Rails app now.

Comment: don't assume: read the documentation for that `.get()` function you're using (explained as part of the API for whatever that `$http` thing you're using is) and then write code for that. On that note: always add all the details to a question: which framework are you using? is this client side or server side? what does the API say? etc. Usually in the process of adding all that information, you find the answer yourself, slap yourself on the forehead for missing something obvious, and then you don't even have to post the question, you solved your own problem already.

Comment: if that's jquery, then `success` would contain the server response, so `console.log(success)` to see what you got back.

Comment: it seem some old AngularJS exmple... In that case the success and eror functions have arguments one of these, the first , contains the data dat you have to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAJOR EDIT:

This is the version (1.4.9) that the OP is using.

In the [**AngularJS $http Documentation v1.4.9**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/api/ng/service/$http) you get a sample script of what you are trying to do.

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: Even better in old angular doc https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/docs/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks @rick. i added it to the answer

Comment: wait so should I use the old one or the one you mentioned you above? Or does it not matter?

Comment: @Kahsn depends on your version of angular. usually you should prefer the newer, unless the newer isn't available in your version.

Comment: @Kahsn it depends on the version that you are using. The bottom sample is from version 1.3.17

Comment: I see. If I'm using version 1.4.9, it's better to use the above one then right?

Comment: @Kahsn I have updated my answer with your version of angular

Answer (score -2):

inside succes call back write

```
console.log(success)
```

so your code must look like this

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/documents/2.json')
            .success(
                    function(success){
                        console.log("Success");
                        console.log(success);
                    })
            .error(
                    function(error){
                            console.log("error has occurred")
        });
```

parameter(success) in function is data, that you receive from server,
instear of success you can write anything you want .. usually i write data .. so in my case it will be function (data)